# Correlated subqueries using Ecto

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto, correlated-subquery

How would you go about writing a correlated subquery in `Ecto`?

For example, what would be the equivalent of the SQL `SELECT` query:

```
--Heaviest Lemmings per Group
SELECT ld.group_name, ld.id, ld.name, ld.weight
FROM lemming_data ld
WHERE weight = (
    SELECT max(weight)
    FROM lemming_data
    WHERE group = ld.group_name
);
```

in `Ecto` syntax? I'm not sure how to refer to the outer query's `group_name`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Co-related subqueries are not possible in Ecto without using fragments. So it would be something like:

```
from ld in "lemming_data",
  where: ld.weight in fragment("(SELECT max(weight) FROM lemming_data WHERE group = ?)", ld.group_name),
  select: ld # or {ld.group_name, ld.id, ld.name, ld.weight}
```

or:

```
from ld in "lemming_data",
  where: fragment("? = (SELECT max(weight) FROM lemming_data WHERE group = ?)", ld.weight, ld.group_name),
  select: ld # or {ld.group_name, ld.id, ld.name, ld.weight}
```